# Should a PHP application perform error handling on incorrect database values?

Tags: php, database

Imagine this... I have a field in the database titled 'current_round'. This may only be in the range of 0,1,2,3.

Through the application logic, it is impossible to get a number above 3 or less than 0 into the database.

Should there be error checking in place to see if the value is malformed (i.e. not in the range 0-3)? Or is this just unnecessary overhead? Is it OK to assume values in a database are correctly formatted/ranged etc (assuming you sanatise/evaluate correctly all user input?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generally don't validate all data from the database.  Instead I try to enforce constraints on the database.  In your case depending on the meaning of 0, 1, 2, 3 I might use a lookup table with a foreign key constraint or if they are just numeric values I might use a check constraint (differs from DB vendor to the next).

This helps protect against changes made to the DB by someone with direct access and/or future applications that may use the same DB but not share your input validation process.

Answer (score 2):

Wherever you decide to place validation prior to insertion in the database is where you should catch these things.

The process of validation should take place in one place and one place only. Depending on how your application is structured:

- Is it procedural or object oriented?
- If it is object oriented, then are you using an Active Record pattern, Gateway pattern or Data Mapper pattern to handle your database mapping?
- Do you have domain objects that are separate from your database abstraction layer?

Then you will need to decide on where to place this logic in your application.

In my case, domain objects contain the validation logic and functions with data mappers that actually perform the insert and update functions to the database. So before I ever attempt to save information to the database, I confirm that there are valid values.

Answer (score 2):

Get the database to do this for you. Most advanced DBMS (check out free DB2 Express-C at http://FreeDB2.com) allow you to define constraints. This way you are getting the database to ensure semantic integrity of your data. Getting this done in application code will work at the beginning but you will invariably find down the line that it will stop working for various reasons. You may have additional applications populate data in to the database or you may get a bug creeping in to existing app. The thing that happens most often is you get new people to work on the application and they will add code that will fail to perform the same level of checking that you have done.

Comment: This is a great idea... something I need to look into more. I am currently only enforcing data type and length on my columns.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should check for what you're expecting, either value or type. And act appropriately. Only *after* it fails all checks should maybe some code think about working out what to do with the 'wrong' value and how to fix things. This applies with a state value, like what you have, or with an input type that needs to be the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

The constraints should be put on the database, just remember to catch any exceptions thrown if your application would by any chance try to insert/update an invalid value